# jq div display script webkit issues

Tags: jquery, cross-browser

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#chekboxes  a').click(function(e) {
        $('.visible').removeClass('visible').addClass('invisible');
        var thediv = $(this).attr('href');
        $(thediv).removeClass('invisible').addClass('visible');
    })
});
```

This simple bit of jq works in FF and not in Chrome and Safari.

Despite googling widely, I cannot tell whether there's a way to make it work in Safari and Chrome or not.

Does anyone know a fix or what is wrong ?

html: [html-pastie](http://pastie.org/1466221)

Thanks, Tom

Comment: Please provide the relevant HTML, and what you intend to occur, and what happens instead.

Comment: **How** does it not work? Which part fails? Making everything invisible, making the relevant bit visible, all of it?

Comment: you can probably do away with the class .invisible (unless it requires its own css), and from javascript just check whether hasClass('visible'). they seem to be logical compliments, which means you only need one.

Comment: @davin: "complements" (with an 'e'), not "compliments"

Comment: @T.J. Crowder, my compliments to you, sir

Comment: thank you everyone - what doesn't work in Webkit is the display of the divs. Clicking on the anchors produces nothing. In FF clicking makes the intended div which happens to have an image in it display as hoped for. The jq is part of a form. I am just using it to review uploaded images.

Comment: @Tom: The questions above remain, though: Supply the HTML and CSS. Without them, people are left to guess, and reasonable guesses suggest that the code quoted above should work.

Comment: OK I dunno how to debug using Firebug and Developer Tools. CSS yes, not JS. To learn.

Comment: @Tom: Re your linked HTML: Sorry, but two things: 1. StackOverflow should stand alone, so put the markup and such *in your question*, not as a link to an external resource that can disappear, get moved, etc. 2. Provide anything you think may be **relevant** but do try to keep it only to the relevant bits. A wall of code will tend to turn off people who might otherwise answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

*Note: This answer is as of [this revision of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4702514/revisions) which doesn't offer any HTML or CSS to work with. If something is subsequently clarified after I've left (it's night time here in the UK), the below may become outdated.*

---

Fundamentally, that code [seems to work](http://jsbin.com/aleso4/2) if we make various assumptions about your markup and intent.

This is a **total** stab in the dark, but: You're using the `href` of an anchor directly as your selector for which div to make visible. Have you inspected the actual value you get back on Safari and Chrome? Could it be that it's a complete URL rather than (say) just a `#foo` or similar? Note that both Safari and Chrome have built-in dev tools (you may need to enable them in Options) that will let you step through that code and inspect values easily in a debugger.

Now, my specific example of the `href` value above (expecting the anchor only and getting the whole thing) isn't it according to [this quick test](http://jsbin.com/aleso4), but the fundamental point holds: Look at the value you're getting and step through the code, on both (say) Firefox (using Firebug) and on Chrome or Safari using Dev Tools.

Comment: The form is just html with some php and data pulled in from a simple database. The CSS isn't complex - probably kludge-filled. But not complicated. The Jquery is simple too. I guess, my most basic question is whether in principle it ought to work in Webkit browsers. Thanks for your answer by the way. Tom

Comment: @Tom: *"The form is just html...The CSS isn't complex..."* And yet, they're clearly where the problem is. Why not quote them in your question? You can edit your question -- just click the **edit** link under it. *"I guess, my most basic question is whether in principle it ought to work in Webkit browsers"* Yes, it should -- if you try the link at the top of my answer in a WebKit browser, for instance, it works... Best,

Comment: Mr or Ms Crowder - thanks again. viz html and css, I've put a link to the html as an edit to OP. You diagnosis must be right, so will look again there. The darnedest thing is: in Chrome, the effect of clicking the Firebug icon is somehow to activate the script so it works. Bizarre.

Comment: my guess now is that there's some relation to the presence of the form